# How to reestablish a Bluetooth connection after I leave an activity in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, bluetooth

I am working on a project that can send and receive Strings to and from an Arduino to control and monitor various sensors and lights. I am running into an issue where once I leave the activity that connects to Bluetooth and then return to that same activity after visiting the home activity I am no longer able to send and receive data. The sending and receiving of strings works perfectly until I leave the activity to go to the home activity and come back.

**Here is the Java code for the sensor activity:**

```
package com.example.arduinocontrol;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class uvlight extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener{
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private CardView uvLight;
    //listeners for button presses
    Button on, off,clear;
    //textbox below buttons
    TextView t1,t2,t3;

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothDevice mDevice;
    ByteArrayInputStream mSocket;
    ConnectedThread mConnectedThread = null;
    ConnectThread mConnectThread = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        //Instantiation
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_uvlight);



        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"BT not supported!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            //opens a window to ask user to turn on bluetooth
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {

                    mDevice = device;

            }
        }

        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(mDevice);
        mConnectThread.start();


        try {
            setw();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private void setw() throws IOException {
        //text for bluetooth device details
        t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.response);

        t2.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());


            String name = mDevice.getName().toString();

            try {
                t1.setText("Connected to:  " + name);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        //links on and off to their element IDs
        on=(Button)findViewById(R.id.uvlighton);
        off=(Button)findViewById(R.id.uvlightoff);
        clear=(Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);

        //clears log text
        clear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                t2.setText("");
            }
        });


        on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //sends 'o' char to Arduino
                // method to turn on uv light
                if(mConnectedThread != null) {
                    //String sig = "o";
                    //mConnectedThread.write(sig.getBytes());
                    int sig = 112;
                    mConnectedThread.write(sig);
                }
            }
        });


        off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //method to turn off uv light
                if(mConnectedThread != null) {
                    //String sig1 = "f";
                    //mConnectedThread.write(sig1.getBytes());
                    int sig = 113;
                    mConnectedThread.write(sig);

                }
            }
        });


    }
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
        //HC-05 unique uuid
        private final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;
            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

                    try {
                        //creates RFCOMM socket
                        tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                        //shows user they are connected
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to your Arduino", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //displays bt info in text field
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to connect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    mmSocket = tmp;

        }
        public void run() {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                //need the if for this edge case

                    try {
                        mmSocket.connect();
                    } catch (IOException connectException) {
                       try {
                        if (mSocket != null) {
                            mSocket.close();
                        }
                        } catch (IOException closeException) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to connect socket!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        return;
                    }

                    //new connected thread obj
                    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
                    mConnectedThread.start();

            }

        public void cancel() {

                    try {
                        mmSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


        }
    }
    //Thread for bluetooth process
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        //copies bt socket for threading
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        //copies input stream obj for threading
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        //copies output stream obj for threading
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

                    try {
                        tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    try {
                        tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                mmInStream = tmpIn;
                mmOutStream = tmpOut;

        }
        //reads from Arduino
        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int begin = 0;
            int bytes = 0;

                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            bytes += mmInStream.read(buffer, bytes, buffer.length - bytes);
                            for (int i = begin; i < bytes; i++) {
                                //end char for a given message from Arduino
                                if (buffer[i] == "#".getBytes()[0]) {
                                    mHandler.obtainMessage(1, begin, i, buffer).sendToTarget();
                                    begin = i + 1;
                                    if (i == bytes - 1) {
                                        bytes = 0;
                                        begin = 0;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

        }

        //writes to the output stream (in this case the Arduino)
        public void write(/*byte[] bytes*/int num) {

                try {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sending bytes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mmOutStream.write(num);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


        }

        public void cancel() {

                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //displays toast message
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    //Suppresses an annoying handler lear warning
    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            int begin = (int)msg.arg1;
            int end = (int)msg.arg2;


            switch(msg.what) {
                case 1:
                    String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                    writeMessage = writeMessage.substring(begin, end);

                    //sends message to homepage to turn cardview red
                    //string called error contains value of writeMessage
                    Intent intent = new Intent("errorCode").putExtra("error", writeMessage);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(uvlight.this).sendBroadcast(intent);

                    //write message to the scrolling textbox
                    t2.append(writeMessage);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

}
```

**Here is the Java code for the home activity:**

```
package com.example.arduinocontrol;


import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private CardView airPump, flowMeter, humiditySensor, levelSwitch1, levelSwitch2, lightStrip, phMeter, uvLight, waterPump, solenoidValve, nutrientPump;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        //defines cards
        airPump = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.airpump);
        flowMeter = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.flowmeter);
        humiditySensor = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.humiditysensor);
        levelSwitch1 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.levelswitch1);
        levelSwitch2 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.levelswitch2);
        lightStrip = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.lightstrip);
        phMeter = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.phmeter);
        uvLight = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.uvlight);
        waterPump = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.waterpump);
        solenoidValve = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.solenoidvalve);
        nutrientPump = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.nutrientpump);
        //click listeners
        airPump.setOnClickListener(this);
        flowMeter.setOnClickListener(this);
        humiditySensor.setOnClickListener(this);
        levelSwitch1.setOnClickListener(this);
        levelSwitch2.setOnClickListener(this);
        lightStrip.setOnClickListener(this);
        phMeter.setOnClickListener(this);
        uvLight.setOnClickListener(this);
        waterPump.setOnClickListener(this);
        solenoidValve.setOnClickListener(this);
        nutrientPump.setOnClickListener(this);


        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("errorCode"));


    }

    //turns Uvlight card red when an error is sent
    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String errorMsg = intent.getStringExtra("error");
            if (errorMsg.equals("-3")){
                uvLight.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i;

        //on click opens the new activity
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.airpump : i = new Intent(this,Airpump.class); startActivity(i); break;
            case R.id.flowmeter : i = new Intent(this,Flowmeter.class); startActivity(i); break;
            case R.id.humiditysensor : i =new Intent(this,Humiditysensor.class); startActivity(i); break;
            case R.id.levelswitch1 : i = new Intent(this,Levelswitch1.class); startActivity(i); break;
            case R.id.levelswitch2 : i = new Intent(this,Levelswitch2.class); startActivity(i); break;
            case R.id.lightstrip : i = new Intent(this,Lightstrip.class); startActivity(i); break;
            case R.id.phmeter : i = new Intent(this,Phmeter.class); startActivity(i); break;
            case R.id.uvlight : i = new Intent(this,uvlight.class); startActivity(i); break;
            case R.id.waterpump : i = new Intent(this,Waterpump.class); startActivity(i); break;
            case R.id.solenoidvalve : i = new Intent(this,solenoidvalve.class); startActivity(i); break;
            case R.id.nutrientpump : i = new Intent(this,Nutrientpump.class); startActivity(i); break;
            default:break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to Android Studio and this is the first time I have had to make a multi-threaded application. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to extract the Bluetooth connection method into a simple profit class, similar to "local broadcast manager". When "uvlight" on destroy Bluetooth connection will continue to open. Or you can refer to GitHub's excellent open source libraries, such as: https://github.com/akexorcist/BluetoothSPPLibrary 。 I believe you can learn more in it

Comment: In my code the Bluetooth connection is on a separate thread from the UI. I think my problem may have a simple fix, but I am unsure of what it is. Maybe it has to do with onPause() or onResume()? onResume() in uvlight is where my connection stops working. Any clue as to why this is? This issue is driving me crazy.